# Using PHP to echo specific data from MySQL rows?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Here's an example of my MySQL table:

```
id, type, value
1, total_clicks, 15
2, total_revenue, 32.42
3, conversion_rate, 1.432
```

I'm using this command to get all of those rows:

```
SELECT * FROM statistics
```

How can I use PHP to echo the `value` column based upon what's in the `type` column?

For example, how would I do something like this:

```
echo "We found that $total_clicks generated $total_revenue in revenue.";
```

Normally I would have each of these as a column and use `fetch_assoc` to echo the value of each column, but for some reason the decided to break this data up into rows...

Comment: Are there multiple sets of data in the output of the query (i.e. more than 1 row where `type` is `total_clicks`)?

Comment: No, the `type` field is unique.

Comment: The reason this is broken up into rows is that's how you normally express relational data, as in it's a common [normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options to store the results from the query and then output them in PHP:

1. an associative array

```
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $data[$row['type']] = $row['value'];
    }
    echo "We found that {$data['total_clicks']} generated {$data['total_revenue']} in revenue.";
```

2. [variable variables](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

```
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        ${$row['type']} = $row['value'];
    }
    echo "We found that $total_clicks generated $total_revenue in revenue.";
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!  Will select answer in a few mins when SO lets me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One method uses aggregation:

```
select replace(replace('We found that [total_clicks] generated [total_revenue] in revenue.',
                       '[total_clicks]',
                       max(case when type = 'total_clicks' then value end)
                      ), '[total_revenue],
                      max(case when type = 'total_revenue' then value end)
              )
from statistics;
```

Comment: That's certainly an unexpected answer, but quite interesting.

Comment: "How can I use PHP to" - I've found a few ways with MySQL to do it, just trying to avoid that if possible.